unity build error occurred: Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeDexRelease'
I used google-signin-unity plugin on my game.
But this issue happened when I built android apk on unity.
unity version is 2022.3.16f1.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:mergeDexRelease'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
There was a failure while executing work items
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
Type com.google.googlesignin.GoogleSignInFragment$State is defined multiple times:
 >D:\project\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\build.transforms\b912aa27fde5edc070cb71db7c70b335\transformed\classes\classes.dex, 
 >D:\project\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\mergeExtDexRelease\classes.dex
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

It seems like files in folder below are defined multiple times in another place?
native-googlesignin\src\main\java\com\google\googlesignin
I have searched for fixing long time but it still no solution.
(gradle and AndroidManifest file setting etc)
Does anyone have any idea?
